# Java Inheritance forcing me to do things I don't want when super() is called

Tags: java, inheritance

I'm reading the official Java tutorials on the Oracle website and I am not liking what I see when experimenting with Inheritance.

I created a Bicycle class and a MountainBike class that extends Bicycle. MountainBike is forced to call super() on Bicycle's constructor from within its own constructor, but this is what happens:

```
A Bicycle has been created.
A Bicycle has been created.
A MountainBike has been created.
```

When the classes look like this (snippet):

```
public Bicycle(int speed) {
 this.speed = speed;
 System.out.println("A Bicycle has been created.");
}

public MountainBike(int seatHeight, int speed) {
 super(speed);
 this.setSeatHeight(seatHeight);
 System.out.println("A MountainBike has been created.");
}
```

This is not desired behavior.

1. Is this a common drawback of Inheritance?
2. What do you do in this case?

Comment: What is the problem? That calling the MountainBike constructor also invokes the Bicycle constructor? That is an intended behaviour, otherwise you would have a MountainBike which's Bicycle fields are uninitialized.

Comment: I believe he is more concerned about why the "A Bicycle has been created." gets called twice.

Comment: Agreed, it seems odd to me that "A Bicycle has been created" is printed twice.  Maybe I'm missing something simple.  Where is the code that instantiates the MountainBike class?  Could you post that?

Comment: I don't get the two `A Bicycle has been created.` when I do it... Are you sure you've only got one call to `super` in there?

Comment: The Bicycle output is printed twice because the OP stated "I created a Bicycle class and a MountainBike class that extends Bicycle".  So the first Bicycle output was from the creation of the Bicycle class and the second when the MountainBike was created.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is the drawback?  The `MountainBike` class calls the `Bicycle` constructor and therefore you will see the output of "A Bicycle has been created." before you see the "A MountainBike has been created." output.

If you are saying that you don't want to see the "A Bicycle has been created." output when creating a `MountainBike`, you may want to wrap the creation of the `Bicycle` or `MountainBike` with another class that knows which output to display.  But essentially what you see in the output is what you would expect to see as a `MountainBike` *is* also a `Bicycle`.

```
public class BikeWarehouse {

    public Bicycle buildBicycle(int speed) {
        Bicycle bicycle = new Bicycle(speed);
        System.out.println("A Bicycle has been created.");
        return bicycle;
    }

    public MountainBike buildMountainBike(int seatHeight, int speed) {
        MountainBike mountainBike = new MountainBike(seatHeight, speed);
        System.out.println("A MountainBike has been created.");
        return mountainBike;
    }
}
```

Or you could put a `toString()` method in the `Bicycle` and `MountainBike` classes and then when you create either, you can just have:

```
System.out.println("A " + bike + " has been created");
```

Obviously the `toString()` of the `Bicycle` would return `"Bicycle"` and the `toString()` of the `MountainBike` would return `"MountainBike"`.

I also don't use aspects too often but I believe it is possible to do something similar to the above without littering your code base (if you find the above "littering"), but you may be able to log on creation of your objects using something like AspectJ.  I'm not a big fan normally of too many aspecting based solutions but might be something to consider.

Comment: I believe his issue is that he is seeing "A Bicycle has been created." twice.

Comment: Thanks, digiarnie, you not only gave me an answer to the question that will work in this context, you provided additional solutions which may benefit myself and others.  +1

Answer (score 1):

Answers:

1. This is not drawback. This is a feature. Seriously :-)
2. Move 'System.out.println("A XXX has been created.")' to protected method and use it instead of static invocation of System.out.println.